# Web service using PHP

Tags: php, web-services, iis

I am trying to create web service with `PHP`.

I follow below steps:-

> Step 1:  Download the library from
>   http://sourceforge.net/projects/nusoap/.
>
> Step 2: Run IIS,  go to www root folder location.
>
> Step 3: Create folder, it’s called "WebServiceSOAP" into www root
>   folder.
>
> Step 4: Paste "lib" folder inside your www/WebServiceSOAP/" location
>   from Step 1 download files.
>
> Step 5: Create two files “server.php” and “client.php” into
>   WebServiceSOAP folder location.

When I run `server.php` on browser 
http://localhost/Webservicesoap/server.php?wsdl
Always shows:-

```
"This service does not provide WSDL"
```

Comment: Have you included the `nusoap` properly ?

Comment: This is my source code  Server.php <?php

require_once ('lib/nusoap.php'); 

$server = new soap_server; 

//register a function that works on server 
$server->register('get_message'); 

// create the function 
function get_message($your_name) 
{ 
if(!$your_name){ 
return new soap_fault('Client','','Put Your Name!'); 
} 
$result = "Welcome to ".$your_name .". Thanks for Your First Web Service Using PHP with SOAP"; 
return $result; 
} 
// create HTTP listener 
$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA = isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA) ? $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA : '';
$server ->service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
exit(); 
?>

Comment: Please post the code in your question..\

Answer (score 0):

I guess that your lib was not pointing the correct folder..

More over you shall try with this simple example

```
<?php
require_once('lib/nusoap.php'); // Make sure it points to correct path 
#require_once('nusoap.php'); // Make sure about the path here and below url
$client = new nusoap_client('your server url'); //make sure of this path too
$result = $client->call('hello', array('name' => 'Anuj'));
print_r($result)
?>
```

It should display `hello Anuj`

Comment: Hello sultan Thanks for replying
This is my source code 

Server.php
<?php
require_once ('lib/nusoap.php'); 

$server = new soap_server; 

//register a function that works on server 
$server->register('get_message'); 
// create HTTP listener 
$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA = isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA) ? $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA : '';
$server ->service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
exit(); 
?>

Comment: Could you send me server.php and client.php source code. That would be helpful for me

Comment: Not working Showing below error :- PHP Notice:  Undefined index:  content-type in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Webservicesoap\lib\nusoap.php on line 7631

Comment: Anybody can help me out

Comment: Just fix it for instance i.e., above `7631` line declare some variable for `content-type` to see what happens next.